# woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button Not working with Themosis

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce with Themosis 2.0, when trying to add an item to the basket I get the CSRF token error, as the _token hidden input isn't in the product page.

I have tried to hook the csrf_field function of Themosis into the form using the woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button hook like so in the file [THEME_DIR]/inc/woocomerce.php

```php
<?php
    // File stored in inc/woocommerce.php (for example)
    Action::remove('init', ['WC_Template_Loader', 'init'], 10);
    Filter::add('comments_template', ['WC_Template_Loader', 'comments_template_loader']);
    Action::add('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'csrf_field', 10, 0);
```

The remove action and filter add are both working. The product page template is as follows:

```php
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    @php(do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content'))

    @loop
        @php(do_action('woocommerce_before_single_product'))
        <div id="product-{{ Loop::id() }}" {{ wc_product_class() }}>

           @php(do_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary'))

            <div class="summary entry-summary">
                @php(do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'))
            </div>

            @php(do_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary'))
        </div>
        @php(do_action('woocommerce_after_single_product'))
    @endloop

    @php(do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content'))

@endsection()
```

However the Action::add isn't adding the hidden input field into the form.

How can I add the CSRF token into the add to cart form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working by adding a custom function which calls the existing helper function. Still not 100% sure why the initial version didn't work.

```php
<?php
    // File stored in inc/woocommerce.php (for example)
    Action::remove('init', ['WC_Template_Loader', 'init'], 10);
    Filter::add('comments_template', ['WC_Template_Loader', 'comments_template_loader']);
    Action::add('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'myCSRF', 10, 0);

    function myCSRF() {
        echo csrf_field();
    }
```